# What does this sample map function in sample CouchDB Set mean?

Tags: javascript, database, mapreduce, couchbase

`Couchbase` comes with a big DB of beers. The 2ms fetch time are impressive but I don't understand what the following map function actually does:

```
function(doc, meta) {
  switch(doc.type) {
  case "brewery":
    emit([meta.id]);
    break;
  case "beer":
    if (doc.brewery_id) {
      emit([doc.brewery_id, meta.id]);
    }
    break;
  }
}
```

I can't wrap my brain around it. Where is this `meta` thing coming from?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't wrap my brain around it. Where is this meta thing coming from?

Metadata is supplemented by Couchbase server for every stored document (json or binary). In your view editor you can see meta data in the right pane of the "Preview a Random doc". For example in the screenshot from your question, meta.id will be "`labbat_ontario_breweries_labbat_50`" as seen on the right side.

meta.id is the actual key of the document and its always present for any returned doc including views (even if you are not including key value explicitly into the view output)
e.g. for example this view outputs only doc.name, but metadata still present with any returned row in that view. You can access meta.id element in the json result.

```
function(doc, meta) {
    emit(doc.name,null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also pretty confused at beginning with couchBase

The code you're pointing at is a very powerful function in couchbase. It permits to create a view which pre-process data to be able to access to the view quickly.

The map function is called to create the view, passing each document in the map function:

- meta : The metadata for the stored document, containing expiry time, document ID, revision and other information.

More info here:

http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/Views/views-writing.html